# Indesign 'paste in place' doesn't work

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

It doesn't matter if it's an SVG, Jpeg, Text box or frame, every time I copy (cmmd + c) and paste in place (cmmd + shift + option + v) anything, InDesign paste's it in the centre of the spread.

I've already tried restarting my computer, Downloading the 2020 version (v 15.4) and even manually trashing the system preferences to no avail.

Is this a bug, could it be something to do with my clipboard settings?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: keyboard issue? Does it work if you use the menu item? Tech support such as this is off topic here.

Comment: Might have a shortcut override. Try doing that via Main menu - Edit - Paste in Place. I use paste in place about 417 times a day. Yes, that exact same shortcut. Most likely not a bug.